Using symmetry when calculating phonons with Phonopy (VASP)
I am currently using Phonopy in order to calculate the phonon dispersion of a magnetic insulator via the finite differences approach. I'm following the documetation, and it looks like the INCAR they're using enables the use of symmetry, because ISYM = 1 by default.
My question is whether I should disable the use of symmetries (ISYM = 0 or -1) due to a possible break in the crystal symmetry induced by the atom displacement, or if I can still use symmetries?
